# Porqué me salta este error XAMPP al intentar iniciar MySQL

Tags: mysql, xampp

hace un rato quise iniciar MySQL para trabajar en mi proyecto, pero al intentar iniciarlo me salta el siguiente error:

```
10:41:04  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
10:41:04  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
10:41:04  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
10:41:04  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
10:41:04  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
10:41:04  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
10:41:04  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

Hay alguna forma de solucionar esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalmente este tipo de error se produce cuando el puerto por defecto de MySQL en XAMPP está ocupado por otro servicio o aplicación.

Prueba de cambiar el número de puerto del MySQL del XAMPP (en el archivo de config del MySQL) o comprueba que no haya otro servicio usando el 3306. Para ver esto, lo puedes comprobar en "servicios" de Windows, a ver si hay algún servicio ejecutándose de tipo SQL o MySQL.

Si todo está OK y sigue el problema, comprueba que el archivo de configuración de MySQL en XAMPP sea por defecto de una instalación limpia.

Comment: No hay nada ocupando ese puerto, por lo que procederé a realizar un backup de htdocs y a reinstalar xampp, para ver si esto soluciona el problema

Comment: @JottaArtZ como te fue con el error ?

Comment: Efectivamente, ya pude volver a iniciar MySQL, creo que esa es la única solución, no reinicié ni nada, solo lo reinstalé

Comment: Perfecto Jotta ArtZ, me alegro que se solucionase el problema :)